# What is the best way to detect quoted content from the synchronized Gmail message thread?

Tags: javascript, html

We synchronize Gmail thread which is basically HTML message body. So if there is a thread In reply emails I get these quoted contents

[image]

I need to detect the `div` element of the quoted element and remove them. My question is how to detect the quoted element?

I approached the methods to find the quoted element from this.

https://github.com/nylas/nylas-mail/blob/master/packages/client-app/src/services/quoted-html-transformer.es6#L289

Here they take an element which has id or class is `gmail_quote` and remove it. But it's not possible now.

The regular expression is not a good idea for the html elements.
Is it a good idea to check for tag `<blockquote>`? If so, can't there be an edge case? What's the best solution to explicitly detect the element?

Source code:

```
  function getQuotedContents(html, {includeInline} = {}){

    let quotedText;
    quotedText = _findGmailQuotes(html);
    return quotedText;
 } 

  function _findGmailQuotes(doc) {
  // Gmail creates both div.gmail_quote and blockquote.gmail_quote. The div
  // version marks text but does not cause indentation, but both should be
  // considered quoted text.
  return Array.from(doc.getElementsByTagName('blockquote'));
}

function removeElements(elements){
  var el, i, len;
  if (elements == null) {
    elements = [];
  }
  for (i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    el = elements[i];
    try {
      if (el.parentNode) {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
      }
    } catch (_error) {
      continue;
    }
  }
  return elements;
}

const getElementsWithoutQuotes = (rawHtml) => {
  const doc = _parseHTML(rawHtml);
  const quoteText = getQuotedContents(doc);
  const docWithoutQuotedElements = removeElements(quoteText);
  return _outputHTMLFor(docWithoutQuotedElements);
}
```

Comment: This is tagged with React, do you have some example code? From what context are you trying to remove the elements?

Comment: I use Reactjs. I will remove the tag.

Comment: So the page has been rendered, outside of your control, and then you want to remove the quoted stuff, right? Can you post example HTML and the expected output, or a link to such a page? Sounds like it shouldn't be complicated, probably

Comment: Yes, the page is been rendered and then I want to remove the quoted stuff. It's not out of control. Updated with source code. Expected output is like I wanna separate quoted-element how Gmail does.